# TextInput: Underline possible to be longer than the place holder text?

Tags: react-native

I want the text input underline placeholder to be longer than the text to look nice and neat. However it only expands when the user is typing more letters. Is there any way possible to set it longer as default?

Also another problem I am having is that in my [password text input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoD5Z.jpg) it is not showing all the text it is only showing PASSWOR.

here is my textinput codes:

```
<View 
            style={styles.inputContainer}
            >
                {/** USERNAME TEXT INPUT**/}
                <TextInput
                style={styles.usernameInput}
                placeholder= "USERNAME"
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                maxLength= {15}

                autoCorrect={false}
                underlineColorAndroid='blue'

                >

                </TextInput>


                {/** PASSWORD TEXT INPUT**/}
                <TextInput
                style={styles.passwordInput}
                placeholder= "PASSWORD"
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                maxLength= {15}

                autoCorrect={false}
                underlineColorAndroid='blue'
                secureTextEntry={true}

                >

                </TextInput>
            </View>
```

and this is my styles codes:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

Container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},

inputContainer: {

    height: '80%',
    width: '80%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(216,69,69,0.8)',
    borderRadius: 50,

},

usernameInput: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
},

passwordInput: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change styleSheet like this and tell me result?

```
Container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},

inputContainer: {

    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(216,69,69,0.8)',
    borderRadius: 50,

},

usernameInput: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    width: 120,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
},

passwordInput: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    fontSize: 20,
    width: 120,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
},
```

Comment: i changed it to the following with editing all the width because width required something like this => width: '120' and it gives me the error " error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: androidtextinput

Comment: I appreciate the help amir =) can you tell me what were the changes that you've made so I can learn too while doing the necessary things.

Comment: oh sorry , set width: 120 instead width: '120',value must be a number

Comment: ohhhh I've already done that when I copy pasted your line. It returns an error " error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: androidtextinput"